# Как через CSS изменить цвет фонового изображения формы, не задев второй фон?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы когда форма становилась в фокусе, менялся не только цвет заливки фона, но и цвет изображения с замком с чёрного на фиолетовый.

На макете изображено четыре состояния для стилизации формы. Изменения цвета замка должно происходить именно за счёт стилизации, а не путём подмены фонового изображения. Никак не приложу ума как это реализовать.

```css
.lorem {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 26px 0 12px 0;
}

.input-text-2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 47px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 296px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/44x44/0000ff/ff0000?text=Foto_1) no-repeat 19px 50%, #fff;
}

.input-text-2:focus {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/44x44/ff0000/0000ff?text=Foto_2) no-repeat 19px 50%, #e9f8ff;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</div>
<input type="text" class="input-text-2" value="Input value" placeholder="Input text placeholder">
```

[image: Макет]

Comment: Если использовать картинку `png || jpg и т.д. и т.п.` ни как....  Можно заменить значок на `svg` по тогда на чисто `css` не выйдет, тогда только `js`...  Вариант который ты хочешь можно реализовать, если воспользоваться  одной из библиотек на подобии `fontawesome`, тогда значок  должен располагаться ниже `input` по иерархии и синтаксис таков   `.input-text-2:focus ~ i {color:red;}`

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать.